# Mobile app to iot communication in azure iot hub

Tags: azure, real-time, iot, azure-iot-hub

I want to implement the following system.

There are users and each user will have an IoT device. The user should be able to do the following:

1. Login with their email and password.
2. Control the IoT device in real time (the user will perform some operation on the IoT device and the result will be displayed instantly on the app).
3. See the state of IoT device in real time. If something changes on the IoT device it should reflect on the app in real time.

I was wondering if this is doable using azure IoT Hub. I came across an architecture where the device is connected to IoT hub and the app is connected to signalR. The messages from IoT device will go to IoT Hub which will update the app using signalR.

But is there any way we can not have additional component like signalR? Can IoT device and mobile app be connected directly to azure IoT hub and exchange data between them without an entity in between other than IoT hub?

Connecting mobile app to IoT hub seems like an option but I did not find any way to implement email and password based authentication to allow users to connect to IoT hub.

Any help in this regard is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could absolutely go without SignalR. You can use the [IoT Hub Service SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-sdks#azure-iot-hub-service-sdks) to send C2D messages to your device from your phone, and also listen to the device telemetry with the same SDK.

However, it would probably be a better idea to have some restrictions on what you can do with that SDK. If the user first has to log in, I take it that they don't get access to every device in your application? Using some kind of role-based access might be preferable, you would build an API for that, which then uses the Service SDK to give you the data.

Also, even though you could listen to the device data directly from your phone, that means that if you have bad reception/wifi, data might not be received. You might want to consider storing it somewhere? I don't know the details about your application, but if you would then want to listen to events from that storage and send it to your app... SignalR might not be the worst idea.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. Like you said a user will not have access to all the devices. So a role based access control will definitely be required. The requirement would be that a user can only access 1 device. Is this possible to implement in IoT hub without using anything else?

Also is email and password based auth possible in IoT hub? Could you point me to the right resource which explain how to do this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Both those requirements are not by default built into IoT Hub. Hub is just a service for communication and configuration and doesn't have those features built-in. You will have to build some kind of data storage that links a user to a device, so your software knows what device to access.

Answer (score 0):

"See the state of IoT device in real time. If something changes on the IoT device it should reflect on the app in real time."

For this EventGrid integration (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-event-grid ) would help. For realtime telemetry as Matthijs said SignalR would be a better choice.If you are fine with some delay (say 10 sec) then Azure Time Series Insights can also be used.